# how to hide/unhide menu strip on main window in WPF(using frames and pages)

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i have created a application with main pages. and as per the login i wan to show/hide different items to a user depending on his user level.
how can i access the menu strip i created in the main window from other pages.(i.e other than main window)
for example:-
i have 3 pages

Master window-main page contains menu strip
This window has only menu strip, few text boxes to show text. and a frame control where the other pages are loaded

Login Window-different page

user window-another page after login

(hope i am clear) i am using frames to navigate in the application
when application launches it will open login page. it must not show menu strip
after login depending on the user the menu items must be visible.
how to do that

Comment: are you following MVVM?

Comment: yes. but in the login window i am trying to navigate on button click. it will check for valid user and navigate to the page

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called Visibility. Bind this with your ViewModel.

This is a code of textblock which visibility can be changed through ViewModel.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage}" Visibility="{Binding IsStatusMessageVisible}" Foreground="Red" Background="#ffc8c8c8" />

public System.Windows.Visibility IsStatusMessageVisible
{
    get
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StatusMessage))
            ? System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
            : System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

This actually checks if StatusMessage is empty then do not display the TextBlock. You can use this in your MenuStrip I guess.

Comment: thanks but how to call it in different page. like i said. from login page or user window.

Comment: I am not sure what actually your application is like. I am assuming that there is one MainWindow and different views (login, logout).

Comment: yes. one main window, contains only menu strip, status bar, etc. this is the main window. it has a frame. and pages login, logout, etc.now i need to hide the menu when the login page is loaded in frame of the main window. sorry if i was unclear in my question. i changed it. i am using frames

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry its quite late reply, however probably it would be useful anyone else looking this.

```
    void MenuItemShowHideManager_OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
                var navService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);

                var window = new MasterPages.MyMasterWindow
                    {
                        MenuItem1 = {Visibility = Visibility.Hidden},
                        MenuItem2 = {Visibility = Visibility.Hidden},
                        MenuItem3 = { Visibility = Visibility.Visible }

                    };

             //Navigate to your default screen      
  }
```